# React rerender when destructuring props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

while investigating a performance issue I found out that when destructuring props inside a component I am actually triggering a rerender. This does not happen if I am using props.propName or if I am destructuring the props object directly into the component paramenters:

```
// Rerendering
const StatefulLayout = (props) => {
  const {isLoading, requestFn, initializationArray} = props
  useEffect(() => {
    requestFn(initializationArray);
  }, [initializationArray]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <PageLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>
    </Layout>
  );
```

```
// Not rerendering
const StatefulLayout = ({
  isLoading,
  requestFn,
  initializationArray
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    requestFn(initializationArray);
  }, [initializationArray]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <PageLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>
    </Layout>
  );
```

What this happens? What would be the correct pattern?

Comment: afaik there should be no difference between first and second snippets, double check

Comment: There is zero difference between your implementations of the component, they will behave identically. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the different rerendering behaviour.

Comment: Isn't each effect missing requestFn as dependency? The way it is now it might be executed with a stale callback.